# Configure Swashbuckle to recognize WebAPI REST service classes named with the suffix “Service”

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

How do i configure Swashbuckle to recognize WebAPI REST service classes named with the suffix “Service” instead of “Controller”.  I already tweaked WebApi.config to recognize suffix "Service" with the code:

```
var suffix = typeof( 
System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerSelector )
    .GetField( "ControllerSuffix", BindingFlags.Static | 
        BindingFlags.Public );          
if ( suffix != null ) suffix.SetValue( null, "Service" );
```

as recommended in
 https://www.strathweb.com/2013/02/but-i-dont-want-to-call-web-api-controllers-controller/

I am able to run the rest service with this, but swagger does not recognize "Service" suffix

Comment: Good question! I personally never seen anyone doing that or having a need for such. My recommendation stick to the standards!

Comment: @HelderSepu ---- Is the use of the suffix "Controller" actually a REST standard? It seems like it is a mistake in WebApi. WebApi evolved from MVC controllers. In MVC there is a controller. But the REST service only helps to get and set data. There is no such thing as a controller.